# Get unique values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

```
[
  {key1 : 'sometext'},
  {key2 : 'sometext'},
  {key1 : 'sometext'},
  {key3 : 'sometext'},
]
```

From the above code I need to get the results as follows, removing objects that contains same keys

```
[
  {key1 : 'sometext'},
  {key2 : 'sometext'},
  {key3 : 'sometext'},
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added an answer please check if that solves your purpose in a better way or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With lodash you can use `_.uniqBy()`, and return the single key of each object:

```js
const arr = [{"key1":"sometext"},{"key2":"sometext"},{"key1":"sometext"},{"key3":"sometext"}]

const result = _.uniqBy(arr, o => _.keys(o)[0])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Using vanilla JS, if you don't care if the 2nd item (the duplicate would be used, you can combine all items to a single object (this will remove the 1st duplicate), get the entries, and map back to an array of objects:

```js
const arr = [{"key1":"sometext"},{"key2":"sometext"},{"key1":"sometext"},{"key3":"sometext"}]

const result = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...arr))
  .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Since the key is a normal string, `_uniqueBy`will serve the purpose, no need to have a custom comparator with `_.uniqueWith`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee - indeed. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

`_.uniqBy(data, _.findKey);`

**Explanation:**

In `_.uniqueBy()` you need to tell on what value you want to derive the uniqueness, either you pass a string as attribute (the value of that attribute will be used in to determine uniqueness), or you pass a callback which will return a value and that value will be considered to evaluate uniqueness. In case the value upon which we will determine the uniqueness is a plain and native value, `_.uniqueBy()` is a better choice, so you don't need to compare manually (which you have to do if your value is a complex object and upon many keys the uniqueness is determined). In our case it is simple `object key`, which can be either `string` or `symbol`, So, the caparison part we can let on `lodash` with `_uniqueBy`

In our  case, if we can return the only key (it must be exactly 1, otherwise none of the logic will work) of each object, `_.uniqueBy()` can do the further, so basically our aim is to pass a callback which will return the only key. we can simply pass a callback to evaluate that like: `e => _.keys(e)[0]`

Now, `_.findkey` takes object as first argument and truthy-ness of the returned value, if it's a truthy then it will return that key (unlike return that entity like `_.find`), so if you don't pass the callback, a default callback valued `a => a` is automatically assigned to handle that case. which means it will check the truthy ness of each entity (key in this case), and obviously, key have to be a truthy value, so it will return the first entity itself (first key here for `_.findKey`), hence passing a callback wrapping findKey with only one argument like `a => _.findKey(a)` is equivalent to pass `_.findKey` callback, we can make it more simple and `_.uniqueBy(data, _.findKey)` will do the job.

*Let's have a snippet:*

```js
let data=[{key1:"sometext"},{key2:"sometext"},{key1:"sometext"},{key3:"sometext"}];

let res = _.uniqBy(data, _.findKey);

console.log('Unique Result: ', res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice use of `_.findKey()`. You should explain how it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

This is using pure javascript, not using loadash

```js
const arr = [
  {key1 : 'sometext'},
  {key2 : 'sometext'},
  {key1 : 'sometext'},
  {key3 : 'sometext'},
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {

   if (!acc.find(x => Object.keys(x).sort().toString() == Object.keys(item).sort().toString() )) {
      acc.push(item)
   }
   
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast solution. Not much iteration.

```js
const data = [
  { key1: "sometext" },
  { key2: "sometext" },
  { key1: "sometext" },
  { key3: "sometext" }
];
const uniqueElementsBy = (arr, fn) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
    if (!acc.some(x => fn(v, x))) acc.push(v);
    return acc;
  }, []);

const isEqual = (x, y) => JSON.stringify(x) == JSON.stringify(y);
console.log(uniqueElementsBy(data, isEqual));

// For complex solution

const isEqual2 = (x, y) => {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(x);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(y);

  if (keys1.length != keys2.length) return false;
  return !keys1.some(key => x[key] != y[key]);
};
console.log(uniqueElementsBy(data, isEqual2));
const data2 = [
  { key2: "sometext", key1: "sometext" },
  { key2: "sometext" },
  { key1: "sometext", key2: "sometext" },
  { key3: "sometext" }
];
console.log(uniqueElementsBy(data2, isEqual2));

const data3 = [
  { key1: "sometext" },
  { key2: "sometext" },
  { key1: "sometext", key2: "sometext" },
  { key3: "sometext" }
];
console.log(uniqueElementsBy(data3, isEqual2));
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: `(x ,y) => JSON.stringify(x) == JSON.stringify(y)` works in this example, but if the order of keys are different it fails for example `{x: 1, y:2}` and `{y:2, x: 1}` it will return false

Comment: it is just a comparator function, he can write comparator function! Stack overflow is not for spoon feeding!

Comment: and in your solution, it won't work with data `{x: 1}, {x:1, x: y}`